# How to makea dynamic id in @Html.Dropdownlist?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm trying to create a dynamic id in @Html.Dropdownlist in a cshml file. No loop is used.

```
 @Html.DropDownList("pub_year_ajax@(Model.UniqueId)", new SelectList(Model.YearsList))

 @Html.DropDownList("pub_year_ajax", new SelectList(Model.YearsList) , new { id = "pub_year_ajax@(Model.UniqueId)" })
```

When the application is run, the id looks something like this:

```
<select id="pub_year_ajax__Model_UniqueId_" name="pub_year_ajax@(Model.UniqueId)">
```

or

```
 <select id="pub_year_ajax@(Model_UniqueId)" name="pub_year_ajax@(Model.UniqueId)">
```

I'd appreciate any pointers.

Comment: Why would you want to do that. The purpose of an `id` attribute is for use in css and javascript selectors which could not be used in this scenario so what you are wanting to do makes no sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the followng should work:

```
@Html.DropDownList("pub_year_ajax", new SelectList(Model.YearsList) , new { id = string.Format("pub_year_ajax{0}", Model.UniqueId) })
```